# Reorder array based on values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have an array with classes (the class is called `Note`), and in those classes are basic values. Two important values are the `Note.Pinned` (boolean whether it's pinned or not) and `Note.Modified` (a timestamp when it was last edited).

I would like to sort this array of classes by the `Modified` timestamp, then reorder it that the `Pinned` notes are on top of this list.

I already tried sorting the notes.

```js
const SortedNotes = Notes.sort((a, b) => a.Modified > b.Modified);
```

`Notes` being the array with classes.

But, then, is there a better way to rearrange this array? Or is this the only method I can use?

```js
SortedNotes.filter(n => n.Pinned).concat(SortedNotes.filter(n => !n.Pinned));
```

The above would work, and I know I can use `Array.prototype.partition`, so is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Please note: [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts *in-place* and modifies the existing array.

Comment: Why not just sort again for notes having the Pinned key be sent to the top?

Comment: To Confirm you want Pinned at the top order by modified.   Pinned been a boolean(true, false), and Modified been a Date type?..

Comment: You can also expand your sort function, so it returns what it does now only if both items have same `Pinned` status, otherwise return 1 if a is pinned and -1 if b is pinned.

Comment: If the Modified is actually a Date type, and Pinned is a boolean, this should work -> `sort((a, b) => Number(b.Pinned) - Number(a.Pinned) || a.getTime() - b.getTime())`  In sorting terminology it's known as a compound index sort.

Comment: `(a, b) => a.Modified > b.Modified` is an inherently unstable return value for sorting.

Comment: @Chris  That's certainly an option, but do be aware some older browsers didn't do stable sort.  Maybe even some modern ones, not sure of the state of stable sort, even Chrome less than version 70 was unstable.

Comment: @Keith, `Note.Modified` is an integer. It's a number between some two dates: `Date.now() - Date.now()` with the last Date.now() being when the note was last modified. So, it returns a number in milliseconds since when it got lastly edited.

Comment: @QSmally in that case it's just -> `sort((a, b) => Number(b.Pinned) - Number(a.Pinned) || a.Modified - b.Modified)`,  if you wanted to do Modified descending, just change the order  `b.Modified - a.Modified`..

Comment: @Keith, indeed. But perhaps it's fine that notes of the same date have the risk of "swapping places". Assuming the incoming order is not important (random, unsorted) then the output should be fine. But you do have a point.

Comment: @Keith That is an interesting statement, `Number(b.Pinned)`. I will try out how that all works and thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Chris I would be amazed if a user is able to create notes at the exact same time to the millisecond.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a short way of converting `true, false` into `1, 0`.   And then a simple subtract will work for sort.   Also with an unstable sort it could be wrong by years, not milliseconds, IOW: on an unstable sort, none specific sorting is random, and it will be down to how internally the browser is doing it.  The only thing you would be able to guarantee is that Pinned is at the top, and none Pinned at the bottom.

Comment: To actually be more specific, down to the specification.  It's only ES2019 that guarantees a stable sort, even ES2018 it was allowed to be unstable.  It's likely not a major issue, as most browser are likely to be using stable sort anyway, but it is something to be aware off.  Creating a compound sort is very easy anyway, so to be on the safe side I'd maybe leave out the double sort trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by multiple conditions:

```js
const SortedNotes = Notes.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.Pinned == b.Pinned) {
    if (a.Modified > b.Modified) return -1;
    if (a.Modified < b.Modified) return 1;
  } else {
    return a.Pinned ? -1 : 1;
  }
});
```

The missing branch of `a.Pinned == b.Pinned && a.Modified == b.Modified` would return `undefined`, which in turn would be interpreted as equal.

Btw, the array `Notes` itself would've been modified in place, so both `SortedNotes` and `Notes` would exhibit the same ordering; of course, assigning to a `const` variable can't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the pinned sorting requirement to the sort:

```js
const arr = [{
    pinned: false,
    modified: 7
  },
  {
    pinned: false,
    modified: 6
  },
  {
    pinned: true,
    modified: 2
  },
  {
    pinned: false,
    modified: 4
  },
  {
    pinned: true,
    modified: 1
  },
  {
    pinned: true,
    modified: 8
  },
  {
    pinned: false,
    modified: 3
  },
]

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.pinned != b.pinned)
    return a.pinned ? -1 : 1;
  return b.modified - a.modified;
})

console.log(arr)
```

As long as the execution of the sort function returns the same result for the same two given parameters the sort will work fine. Knowing this, you can handle the two states where the pinned state is different and then sort by modified only if the pinned state is the same.

Comment: I've edited it to remove the number of checks required each call. It's now: If the pinned state is different and the first item is pinned put it before the second item otherwise put it after, else sort by modified as normal.

Comment: If you'd like an even shorter version, try this -> `arr.sort((a,b)=>(b.pinned|0)-(a.pinned|0)||b.modified-a.modified);`

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution perhaps, but this should help you in the right direction.
This sorts the array so that notes are in decending date order, with the pinned ones at the top.

Unlike other (better) answers, this has a O(2n) sorting complexity, so bear that in mind.

```js
const notes = [
  {
    text: "foo",
    modified: 1583337610387,
    pinned: false
  },
  {
    text: "bar",
    modified: 1583337610388,
    pinned: true
  },
  {
    text: "baz",
    modified: 1583337610389,
    pinned: false
  },
  {
    text: "qux",
    modified: 1583337610390,
    pinned: true
  }
];

const sortedNotes = [...notes];
sortedNotes.sort((a, b) => a.modified > b.modified ? -1 : 1);
sortedNotes.sort((a, b) => (a.pinned === b.pinned) ? 0 : a.pinned ? -1 : 1);
console.log(sortedNotes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter, you can try

```
const SortedNotes = Notes.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.Pinned > b.Pinned)
       return 1;
    if (a.Pinned == b.Pinned) 
       return a.Modified > b.Modified;
    return -1;
})
```

Comment: This compare function would return the same for `a.Modified == b.Modified` as well as `a.Modified < b.Modified` ... this isn't guaranteed to be well supported.

Answer (score 0):

I edited @Ja͢ck's answer to be a little more compact.

```js
const SortedNotes = Notes.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.Pinned == b.Pinned) return a.Modified > b.Modified ? -1 : 1;
    else return a.Pinned ? -1 : 1;
});
```